# Why is copy constructor called twice?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have the following code snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

class Move {
    private:
        int* data;
         
    public: 
        void set_data_value(int d) {
            *data = d; 
        }
        int get_data_value(){
            return *data; 
        }

        Move(int d);
        Move(const Move &source);
        ~Move();
};

Move::Move(int d) {
    std::cout << "ctor being called" << std::endl; 
    data = new int; 
    *data = d; 
}

Move::Move(const Move& source) {
    std::cout << "copy ctor being called" << std::endl;
    data = new int; 
    *data = *source.data;
}

Move::~Move() {
    std::cout << "deleting Move" << std::endl; 
    delete data; 
}
int main() {
    Move x{1};
    
    Move y{x}; 

    std::vector<Move> vec; 
    vec.push_back(x);
    vec.push_back(y);

    return 1; 

}
```

Here is the output:

```
ctor being called
copy ctor being called
copy ctor being called
copy ctor being called
copy ctor being called
deleting Move
deleting Move
deleting Move
deleting Move
deleting Move
```

My question is: why is the copy constructor being called 4 times when I see only 3 copies? (1 from `Move y{x}` and two from the two `push_back()` calls)

Comment: What you describe is not guaranteed, but is probably due to the vector only having capacity of `1` after the first call of `push_back()`, so having to resize (and copy elements) during the second call of `push_back()`.

Answer (score 6):

You miss to count reallocations of the vector. Add this lines to your code:

```
int main() {
    Move x{1};
    
    Move y{x}; 

    std::vector<Move> vec; 
    std::cout << "capacity: " << vec.capacity() << "\n";
    vec.push_back(x);
    std::cout << "capacity: " << vec.capacity() << "\n";
    vec.push_back(y);
    std::cout << "capacity: " << vec.capacity() << "\n";

    return 1; 

}
```

Then possible output is:

```
ctor being called
copy ctor being called
capacity: 0
copy ctor being called
capacity: 1
copy ctor being called
copy ctor being called
deleting Move
capacity: 2
deleting Move
deleting Move
deleting Move
deleting Move
```

The `vector`s capacity starts out as `0` and then increases as needed (factors of 2 or 3 are common). You can see that when the capacity increases from 1 to 2, there is a call to the copy constructor to copy that one element that is already in the vector to a different place in memory.

Note that the output of the above can be different. Allocation strategies are subject to subtle optimizations. Its the requirement of `push_back` having amortized constant complexitiy that implies that capacity cannot grow linear. Though the factor is not necessarily `2`. Some implementations use `3` or a different factor.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much! Is there a way to make sure the vector moves, instead of copy?

Comment: @LionellLohJianAn I would have to look it up to be sure. I think it does move when elements are movable, but your `Move` isnt

Answer (score 2):

It is due to vector increasing in capacity each time the array is no longer sufficient
You can prevent that by reserving some space `reserve()`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve

Comment: I only kept the part about the capacity and the reserve and upvote your answer :)

Comment: The point about `reserve()` is useful, thank you!